# Determining the subspace of a given vectorspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given a vectorspace $\mathbb{R}[X]_{<4}$ of the polynomials of 3rd degree with real coefficients. Suppose W = { P(X) $\in$ $\mathbb{R}[X]_{<4}$ | P'(0) = 0}:

1. Prove that W is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}[X]_{<4}$.
2. Determine the dimension of W.
3. Find a subspace W' of 
   $\mathbb{R}[X]_{<4}$ such that $\mathbb{R}[X]_{<4}$ = W $\bigoplus$ W'.

I know how to prove that W is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}[X]_{<4}$, but I don't know to solve the 2nd and the 3rd questions.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: First of all, your space is actually the space of real polynomials of degree less than $4$. (Provided you stipulate that the zero polynomial has degree $-\infty$.). Then, simply write an element uniquely as $P(x) = a_{0} + a_{1} x + a_{2} x^{2} + a_{3} x^{3}$, and see what the condition $P'(0) = 0$ means for the coefficients $a_{i}$.

Comment: @OSRCK_ Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

For point 2

- $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d\implies p'(x)=3ax^2+2bx+c \quad p'(x)=0 \implies c=0$

thus

- $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+d$

with basis $1,x^2,x^3$ and thus the dimension is $3$.

For point 3 let consider $W'$ of $cx$.

Comment: Make it $c x$ ;-)

Comment: Ops...thanks prof!